# Sorting 2 sets of scores with array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote following code to rank 2 sets of scores:

```
public class ScoreRanking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] score1 = { 9, 3, 6, 19 };
        int[] score2 = { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1 };

        int[] rank1 = sortScores(score1);
        int[] rank2 = sortScores(score2);

        for (int i = 0; i < rank1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ": " + rank1[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("_________\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < rank2.length; j++) {
            System.out.println((j + 1) + ": " + rank2[j]);
        }
    }

    static int[] sortScores(int[] sort) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sort.length - 1; i++) {
            if (sort[i] < sort[i + 1]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                int temp = sort[i];
                sort[i] = sort[i + 1];
                sort[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        return sort;
    }
}
```

The first set is ordered but the second isn't. I played around with the brackets, tried a different order (int score 1... int rank1... int score2... int rank2... / int score2..., int rank2... int score1... int rank1...) - but the score2 is always "ignored". Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: Th error is logical. Your methodology for sorting is flawed. You should look up sorting algorithms.

Comment: what do you mean by ignored

Comment: It appears unsorted in the console, i.e. 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 5

Comment: You can't sort an array in a single loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a cold debug and I think that you're problem is with the sortScores method.
if I'm not wrong the rank2 array is sorted like this {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 5}.

The main problem that your facing is that your algorithm only change the i and i+1 elements, but what happen when your i+2 elements in lower than the i element, there the method fails doesn't do the job correctly.

If you want to develop a sorting algorithm by you I recommend that first make sort an array with 5 or 4 elements in paper and them try to understand what are you doing, them write the steps in pseudo code and finally translate into Java is longer but I guaranteed you that it will be more satisfactory, but if you want to sort the array write now them you should check the sorting algorithms on Wikipedia and take a special look on the [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is easy to understand and doesn't have much complexity.

At last, if you want to used java libraries to save time and code them you should check the [Array class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) the sort(int[] a) method.

I hope that my answers help you to understand better this world.

Bye, Greetings from Venezuela

PD. The Insertion Sort Algorithm is this one:

```
public static void insertionSort (int[] array) {
      for (int i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
         int aux = array[i];
         int j;
         for (j=i-1; j >= 0 && array[j] > aux; j--){
              array[j+1] = array[j];
          }
         array[j+1] = aux;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you looked up sorting algorithms as dev8080 suggested. Your sorting algorithm only goes through the list once, which is unheard of. And while your sorting algorithm may end up working for the first array, for the second array it has problems:

```
if (sort[i] < sort[i + 1])
```

With this condition you're swapping values even if they're equal, which means you're unnecessarily swapping those 3's. This might not have a visible effect, but it is a wasteful operation, and for more complex objects could produce undesirable effects.

At any rate your code only swaps the values when

```
sort[i] = 5 
sort[i + 1] = 1
```

because this is the only place where the first value is less than the second one. This is why you get the result

```
1: 3
2: 3
3: 3
4: 3
5: 3
6: 1
7: 5
```

It looks like you're trying to implement an variant of bubble sort, in which case you should check out this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

keep in mind bubble sort is not very efficient for larger lists